# String.Copy not available in Xamarin PCL project?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

According to the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.String.Copy/p/System.String/) there should be a static String.Copy method available. However it's not available in my setup:

[image]

This is the detailed info about the versions of everything installed:

> === Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===
>
> Version 7.0.1 (build 24) Installation UUID:
>   fda7d9c6-ac7a-446b-895c-2823b983c917 Runtime:     Mono 5.0.1.1
>   (2017-02/5077205) (64-bit)    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>
> Package version: 500010001
>
> === NuGet ===
>
> Version: 4.0.0.2323
>
> === .NET Core ===
>
> Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet SDK:
>   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.3/Sdks MSBuild SDKs:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks
>
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Version: 1.5.4 Location: /Applications/Xamarin
>   Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 7.3.1.2 (Visual Studio Community) Android SDK:
>   /Users/milen/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx     Supported
>   Android versions:
>         4.4 (API level 19)
>         7.1 (API level 25)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5 SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.4 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 25.0.3
>
> Java SDK: /usr java version "1.8.0_111" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
>
> Android Designer EPL code available here:
>   https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Xamarin Inspector ===
>
> Version: 1.2.2 Hash: b71b035 Branch: d15-1 Build date: Fri, 21 Apr
>   2017 17:57:12 GMT
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 8.3.3 (12175.1) Build 8E3004b
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 10.10.0.36 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: d2270eec Branch:
>   d15-2 Build date: 2017-05-22 16:30:53-0400
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Version: 3.4.0.36 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 700010024 Git revision:
>   7ab1ca2ced6f584e56b7a0d4d321d00775cd95c9 Build date: 2017-05-19
>   05:44:51-04 Xamarin addins: 08d17158f3365beee5e60f67999e607cce4b3f93
>   Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-2
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.12.5 Darwin 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0
>       Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017
>       root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

The code is in a PCL with the following profile:

[image]

I couldn't find any info on such a problem. What might be the reason?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.String.Copy/p/System.String/

Comment: That is something the OP already referenced to himself :/

Comment: What type of project are you trying to use this in? PCL? What Profile? .NET Standard? I think that in whatever type of version you are trying to use it now, the `Copy` method isn't available anymore.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I edited my question with the PCL profile. Can you elaborate what do you mean with your last sentence?

Comment: Here it shows up(Visual Studio 2015 Pro Upd 3) , but it also warn: this method is not available for Windows phone and UWP plateform...

Comment: A better question would be why you think you need it. Strings are immutable; constructing copies that differ only by reference is an extremely niche use. I've never invoked `String.Copy` in all my career as a .NET developer (which spans the entire lifetime of .NET). A simple replacement in the unlikely case you do need it (if not a very efficient one) would be `new StringBuilder(s).ToString()`.

Comment: Actually you are right. Getting the reference of an immutable string did the trick! I'm new to .NET and still getting used to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jimbot states in the comments, `String.Copy` is not available on Windows Phone and UWP, maybe it isn't available on some other platforms as well. Using a PCL means that you will get only the support of the parts of the libraries that intersect between all checked platforms.

So in your screenshot, a method has to be available on all platforms that you have checked there. If the method is not available on one, then it won't be accessible for you. That is the way a PCL works. Read more on this in the Xamarin documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/).

To overcome this:

- Either find another way that works with the methods that *are* available to you
- Uncheck the unsupported platforms, nut note you will also lose the ability to run your app on that platform and you need to do a lot of research on what platforms support the `String.Copy` and which one doesn't
- Use a [Shared project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/).

Comment: That clears the clouds. It would've been nice if the documentation made it clear what is available on what platforms!

Comment: Technically it does at the bottom it says what .net frameworks are supporting this method. But I agree that the documentation is outdated considering all the new supported platforms.

Comment: Hm, do you mean this:
"Requirements
Namespace: System
Assembly: mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)
Assembly Versions: 1.0.5000.0, 2.0.0.0, 4.0.0.0"
Because it's giving me zero practical information where I can use this method.